# Server sent events showing blank in chrome devtools for simple express SSE

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, server-sent-events

Here is the simple code sample to send SSE using express program (which is working fine).
Only trouble is the devtools eventStream section is blank.
[image: Empty event stream]

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/countdown', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  })
  countdown(res, 10)
})

function countdown(res, count) {
  res.write(JSON.stringify({ count: count}))
  if (count)
    setTimeout(() => countdown(res, count-1), 1000)
  else
    res.end()
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('SSE app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must format the event like that :

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/countdown', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  });
  countdown(res, 1, 10);
});

function countdown(res, id, count) {
  res.write(`id: ${id}\n`);
  res.write('event: count\n');
  res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ count: count })}\n\n`);
  if (count) setTimeout(() => countdown(res, id + 1, count - 1), 1000);
  else res.end();
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('SSE app listening on port 3000!'));
```

And in your front page use [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventSource) :

```
<script>
  var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/countdown');
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  };
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this formatting convention documented somewhere? @Arkerone

Comment: What's the `\n\n` meanings, and why must we add it?

Comment: @xgqfrms They indicate the end of a message (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server)

Comment: I found it in this article too. https://javascript.info/server-sent-events#server-response-format

Comment: BTW, why does `retry` not work as the document descript? https://github.com/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/issues/3600